# PERMISSION_DENIED when testing PayPal Activity REST API in the sandbox

Tags: rest, paypal

I created a new app and I'm following the API instructions as documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/activities/

My sandbox credentials are good, and I used them to create a bearer token, which I used (in Postman) to post a payment (https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment) with success.

However, my goal for this application is to create an **activity report** using the API functions linked above. For this, I turned on the appropriate "**App feature option**" called **Transaction Search**, in addition to every other app feature option.

Header:

```
Authorization: Bearer (new bearer token here)
```

My GET request:

```
https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/activities/activities?start_time=2018-05-03T15:00:00.000Z&end_time=2018-05-02T15:30:00.000Z&page_size=10&next_page_token=1
```

Whatever I do, I get:

```
HTTP Status: 401 Unauthorized
```

Request body:

```
{
    "name": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "message": "No permission for the requested operation",
    "details": {
        "": "No permission for the requested operation"
    }
}
```

I am a US developer, and this application is for my own use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Final answer (for now), confirmed by a PayPal developer support technician:

PayPal doesn't yet have a REST API method available to the public, for creating this report. Use TransactionSearch in the old NVP (Name-Value-Pair) API, it's reasonably well documented and used everywhere - even though it's been deprecated since 2017.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/?mark=TransactionSearch

For those who like to work with example code, the following GitHub project shows how you could implement the API. It was helpful to me:

https://github.com/gtaylor/paypal-python

Comment: So the activities API is documented really well but it's not supported yet?  We are getting the exact same error following the exact same steps as OP.  Do we really have to use the NVP API just for the activities but use the regular REST API for everything else?

Comment: Yes, I quote: "They are looking into the expanding this feature in the future for the most part it's intended for partners that manage a large number of accounts directly.  The Activity API was not intended to be used a reporting API and though they agreed to look into the matter they are currently not recommending depending on the Activity API for this purpose.  They're recommendation was to utilize Sync API as this was intended for reporting." My problem is that the Sync API is hours behind (at set intervals?), not real-time.